# Android paused app preview image black

Tags: android, navigation, preview

In the list of the paused apps, Android usually shows a small preview image of the app.

However, the preview image is black when I use the following way to hide the navigation bar:

```
         uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
             | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
             | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
             | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN 
             | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
             | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION;

         View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
         decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

If I remove the last two options, the preview is shown correctly. Keep one and the preview is black.
Is this a bug or are there any reasons for this? Are there any workarounds?

Edit: I would like too add that I also see this behaviour on other games that hide the navigation bar, like Plants vs. Zoombies 2....but that could be on purpose.